# Session/User Discrepancies between Views in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I have two views on my website in Google Analytics. Currently, the two have the exact same filters applied to them (I can't yet create a new filter on this account to apply to my test view). I would expect that with the same filters, the two views would report exactly the same data. However, when I compare the views, the session and user counts vary between the two views.

**Metrics from May 29 - June 5**

View #1:

- Sessions: 3708
- Users: 2691

View #2:

- Sessions: 3338
- Users: 1821

I am somewhat alarmed by the difference in users between the two views. Again, I know that different views typically have different filters applied to them, but these two views have the exact same filters applied.

Any idea why I might be seeing this discrepancy?

Comment: Was either of the views either created or edited during that time period?

Comment: @JBrazier I just realized that the second view was created on May 29th, so I switched them both to measure May 30th - June 5th. This brings the user counts closer, but not equal. They are now at 2043 vs. 2479. All the other statistics vary only slightly. The other odd thing that I noticed is that when I sum the data points on the line graph in the audience overview, I come up with a much different user count: 2787. Any idea as to why this is?

Comment: OK, next you need to remove today from the measurement; Google Analytics provides seperate tools for realtime analysis. In addition, you should consider if either view has been edited; I know there aren't any filters now, but were there any at all in that time frame?

The difference between sum of users and total users is because users aren't additive. 100 Users on Monday and 100 Users on Tuesday could be anywhere from 100 users total (if the same people all came back) to 200 (if it's entirely fresh audience).

Comment: The sum of users versus unique users thing makes perfect sense. I changed the date range on each view so that they don't include today.

Comment: The user counts are now 1931 vs. 2349. As far as I know there weren't any changes to the filters. 
Each view has two filters which are used to exclude hits from subdomains. The one thing I did notice upon further investigation is that the filters were applied in reverse order for my second view. I.E. View #1 had filter #1 applied then filter #2 whereas View #2 had filter #2 applied then filter #1. However since the filters serve to exclude subdomains, I would think that the order in which the filters are applied wouldn't matter.

Comment: I'm afraid beyond that there's not much I can say, other than maybe monitor both views for the next few days and see if the results are the same. If, for example, the filters were applied at different times to the two views, that woudl explain the issue. You could also look to see if hits appeared to either of those subdomains in the time period.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This continues to be a mystery to me. Google Analytics does say "You are using a filtered view, which may cause your Users count to be inaccurate", so I guess that could be the explanation. However, it still doesn't make sense to me that the two views with the exact same filters could differ in the way that they record users.